# I need to add social media images in the html string I have in the footer of my site done with js

Tags: javascript, image, footer

I have a website with a footer done with javascript (so it appears in every html page) and I cannot add the social media images, because the images I have in the folder "images" cannot be tracked.
When I write img src="" Visual Studio just doesn't track any route. How can I fix it?

I tried using flaticon and FontAwesomedirectly but I have no idea of how to do that without downloading the images, I have to register for that, right?

Comment: Welcome! Can you post your footer's code here? Also, you don't have to register for Font Awesome - you can include the CDN link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/brands.min.css and then use `<i class="fab fa-facebook">` or whatever social icon class you need (`fab` is the global class that needs to be there);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try writing "./" inside src it may suggest folder path where image is located. if not then there is no path u may not have any folder. P.S : make sure the folder is inside the main folder where u have written index.html file.

If you prefer to use online resources like Font Awesome or Flaticon for your social media icons, you don't need to download the images. you can use Font Awesome icons, for example:

a. Include the Font Awesome CSS in the  section of your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
```

b. Use Font Awesome icons in your footer:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> <!-- Facebook icon -->
<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>  <!-- Twitter icon -->
<!-- and so on... -->
```

For Font Awesome, you don't need to download the icons individually. You reference them by their class names.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know how to use Font Awesome. I could solve it! I did everything again but more organized , with folders, and VS finally found the route.